# Windows 10 Calendar app not syncing properly with iCloud Calendar

Tags: windows-10, google-calendar, icloud, calendar.app

I tried using the Windows 10 Calendar app but while I can edit events fine, when I delete them on the Win10 Calendar app they do not delete in iCal and eventually reappear in the Win10 Cal. The synchronization is also flaky and hangs for long periods of time.

Setting the iCal calendars to public seems like a huge security risk, am I right in thinking this?

The person does not have Outlook so the iCloud software is useless to them.

Is there a decent calendar/contacts application where the sync actually works and it supports Google and iCloud?